# mysql subquery ERROR [21000][1241] Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a table called counterparty.
I'm going to have a query on this table
Something like this:

```
SELECT (`name`, `mark`, `parent`, `description`) AS table_1 FROM (SELECT 
`name`, `mark`, `parent`, `description` FROM counterparty) AS table_2 WHERE 
(table_1.mark <> table_2.parent);
```

But the error below shows:

[21000][1241] Operand should contain 1 column(s)

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below - using [SELF JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_self.asp)

```
SELECT table_1 .`name`, table_1.`mark`, table_1.`parent`, table_1 .`description` 
FROM counterparty table_1 inner join counterparty table_2 
table_1.mark <> table_2.parent;
```

Comment: This query works but can you explain it?
I thought that alias should be placed after the name of the columns.
Something like this:
SELECT (....) AS alias  FROM (...)

Comment: @Sina, this is a self join where you are join with your same table and comparing that yout table1.mark<>table2.parent

Answer (score 0):

you did wrong to write subquery you can try like below by using join

```
SELECT  t1.* from table_1 t1    
 join  (SELECT 
`name`, `mark`, `parent`, `description` FROM counterparty
       ) AS table_2 t2 on  t1.mark!=t2.mark
```